# MySQL - Select INTO variable not working as desired

Tags: mysql

I am facing a problem with the select INTO clause-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_user_signup`(
IN  gender      int,
IN  dob         varchar(50),
IN  location    int,
IN  email       varchar(100),
IN  password    varchar(50),
IN  verify_uuid varchar(256),
IN  fb_user     bool
)
BEGIN
DECLARE User_ID INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ENABLED BOOL DEFAULT TRUE;

SELECT user_id INTO User_ID FROM tbl_user_login WHERE email = email;
CALL sp_debug(ENABLED,1,User_ID,(select concat_ws('',"UserID:", User_ID)));

IF User_ID = 0 THEN
<do something>
ELSE
<do something>
END IF
END
```

My tbl_user_login has values for email - v.psk@gmail.com.
Even though I pass the email v.psk@gmail.com to SP it always goes into IF BLOCK. 
The values of User_ID is zero from the debugs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not doing what you expect:

```
SELECT user_id INTO User_ID FROM tbl_user_login WHERE email = email;
```

The problem is that you think one `email` is a variable and the other a column.  SQL can't read your mind though, so both are the column.

Prefix your variables with something to distinguish them from columns.  For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_user_signup`(
IN  v_gender      int,
IN  v_dob         varchar(50),
IN  v_location    int,
IN  v_email       varchar(100),
IN  v_password    varchar(50),
IN  v_verify_uuid varchar(256),
IN  v_fb_user     bool
)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_User_ID INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ENABLED BOOL DEFAULT TRUE;

SELECT user_id INTO v_User_ID FROM tbl_user_login WHERE email = v_email;
CALL sp_debug(ENABLED,1,v_User_ID,(select concat_ws('',"UserID:", v_User_ID)));

IF v_User_ID = 0 THEN
<do something>
ELSE
<do something>
END IF
END
```